# How to open vapor project on macOS

Tags: ios, swift, macos-mojave, vapor

Hello Here I got an error starting new project with vapor, I've ben follow the instruction from documentation here https://docs.vapor.codes/3.0/getting-started/hello-world/
when I going to step vapor xcode there is an error apear, like bellow :

> backgroundExecute(code: 1, error: "The file /Users/*.xcodeproj does not exist.\n", output: "")

please kindly help me, thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

e.g. clone Vapor api template

```sh
git clone https://github.com/vapor/api-template/
```

then go to `api-template` folder

```sh
cd api-template
```

and then you have two ways to open project

1. Through classic `xcodeproj`

```sh
swift package update && swift package generate-xcodeproj
```

2. Through Swift Package Manager file (available from Xcode 11+)

```
open Package.swift
```

Comment: @imike- At this line "swift package update && swift package generate-xcodeproj" it gives error that @rpath/llbuild.framework/Versions/A/llbuild
  Referenced from: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/swift-package
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6

Answer (score 1):

You’re getting the error because the project generation is failing but annoyingly the toolbox is swallowing the error. And the reason the generation is probably failing is because Homebrew likes to mess up the command line installation of Swift.

So, to fix it run `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app` and try again.

(As a side note, if you’re running Xcode 11 you can just do `open Package.swift` and use Xcode 11’s SwiftPM integration instead which makes for a far better development experience)